# JSON serialisation not supported objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, json-framework

I am getting below error when I am using Dictionary with array of object :

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[jsonDict setObject:checkMarkPresetRecipientsArray forKey:@"Names"];
[jsonDict setObject:checkMarkDocumentGroupNameArray forKey:@"Address"];
json =  [jsonDict JSONFragment];
```

Error : JSONFragment failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=1 \"JSON serialisation not supported for DocumentType\" UserInfo=0xb5cc270 {NSLocalizedDescription=JSON serialisation not supported for DocumentType}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=1 \"Unsupported value for key DocumentTypes in object\" UserInfo=0xb580e60 {NSUnderlyingError=0xb585320 \"JSON serialisation not supported for DocumentType\", NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported value for key DocumentTypes in object}"
)

but not getting same error with :

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Nitesh",@"Name", @"Balaghat",@"Address",nil];
    NSString *json=[jsonDict JSONRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

above gives me correct JSON representation.

What I am doing wrong? can any one help me on above....

Actually my array contains core data class object and it's not supporting JSON representation so I changed by implementation now it's working fine. If is there any way to change coredata class objects representation in JSON please update me. Thanks.

Comment: `JSON serialisation not supported for DocumentType`

Comment: use JSONValue instand of JSONRepresentation

Comment: @graver  - DocumentType is my class object and which I have added in Dictionary with key. Is it not possible to use our class objects ?

Comment: @NiteshMeshram Does your custom class implement the [NSCoding Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: @Abizern - Hi I got your point let me implement that my custom classes is subclass of NSManagedObject, I have tried this but it don't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Abezern @graver @iPatel

Actually my array contains core data class object and it's not supporting JSON representation so I changed by implementation now it's working fine.